# Selecting elements from a large matrix using a sliding window

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, subset, sliding-window

I have a 220*366 matrix, I want to set a 3*3 windows to select elements in matrix.
example:

```
matrix = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
          6, 7, 8, 9, 10;
          11,12,13,14,15];
window = [1, 2, 3;
          6, 7, 8;
          11,12,13];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, this can be done using [`nlfilter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html):

```
function out = q52158450()
% Create a matrix:
Rm = 220; Cm = 366;
matrix = randn(Rm,Cm);

% Define the window and apply filter:
Rw = 6; Rc = 6;
windows = nlfilter(matrix, [Rw, Rc], @getwindow);

% Select subset of outputs, removing zero-padded boundary elements:
Bw = floor((Rw-1)/2); Bc = floor((Rc-1)/2); 
out = windows(Bw:end-Bw, Bc:end-Bc); % < Output is a cell

function out = getwindow(in)
out = {in};
```

Otherwise it can be done with a double loop:

```
function out = q52158450()
% Create a matrix:
Rm = 220; Cm = 366;
matrix = randn(Rm,Cm);

% Define the window and apply filter:
Wr = 3; Wc = 3;
Br = ceil(Wr/2); Bc = ceil(Wc/2);
out = cell(Rm-Br, Cm-Bc);

for indR = 1:Rm-Wr+1
  for indC = 1:Cm-Wc+1    
    out{indR, indC} = matrix(indR:indR + Wr - 1, indC:indC + Wc - 1);
  end
end
```

Comment: @yyk You're welcome! If you found this answer helpful, please consided [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to indicate that your problem is resolved.